# How to rearange columns in txt files using powershell

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

Hello I'm trying to change columns order of a multiple text files in a single directory using powershell and also I need to add a new column with a file name in it.
I would like to rewrite each file and not to create a new one.

example:
File1.txt
original file content:

```
column1;column2;column3
```

new file content - 
File1.txt

```
column2;column3;column1;File1
```

.
.
.
FileN.TXT

Here is what I have so far:

Thank you

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText('FILE1.txt')
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter 'FILE1-NEW.txt'
for(;;) {
$line = $reader.ReadLine()
if ($null -eq $line) {
    break
}
$data = $line.Split(";")

$BaseName = $_.Basename
$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},$BaseName', $data[0], $data[2], $data[1])
}
$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

Comment: How big are the files and how many are there?

Comment: There is about 20 000 txt files. 10 mb each

Comment: In that case I'd proceed like you've done here, and then 1) remove the original file and 2) rename the new/temporary file, after each run

Comment: Hi Mathias, could you please edit my code in order to work for multiple files? There is also problem with adding file name as a last column.My code will add just "$BaseName" text string instead of actual file name.

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're current approach is fine, as long as none of the column values contain the delimiter (`;`).

As suggested in the comments, what you can do at the end of each run is just delete the original file, then rename or move the new/temporary to the original file path.

I'd personally use `Path.GetTempFileName()` to allocate the temporary file:

```
# Gather all the files
$Files = Get-ChildItem .\path\to\files -Filter *.txt

foreach($txtFile in $Files){
    # Allocate new temp file
    $tempFilepath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    # Open up original file for reading
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($txtFile.FullName)

    # Open up temp file for writing
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $tempFilepath
    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($null -eq $line) {
            break
        }
        $data = $line.Split(";")

        # Write data in modified order to temp file
        $writer.WriteLine('{0},{1},{2},{3}', $data[0], $data[2], $data[1], $txtFile.Basename)
    }
    $reader.Close()
    $writer.Close()

    # Move file into place, -Force will overwrite original
    Move-Item $tempFilepath -Destination $txtFile.FullName -Force
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.However for some reason it doesn't work.I made only one change to your code. I've changed second line of your code to $Files = Get-Content .\ -Filter *.txt  to run it from current directory but I got some errors when I tried it to run. I use only single file to test it. My test file looks like this:  column1;column2,column3

Comment: Sorry, second line should be `Get-ChildItem` not `Get-Content`

Comment: Now it works, ALMOST OK.Only problem is that it  doesn't add a file name at the end of each row.It looks like $_.Basename doesn't contain any value. My output now looks like this: column1;column3;column2;      -so file name is not in a last column.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten this a lot and still keep it very readable:

```
$output = Get-Content $FileName | % { write-output "$($_)$FileName;" }
$output >> $FileName
```

Of course you can toss the output directly into the file in 1 line but This leaves the door open for further manipulation down the road.